# Python list of strings and conditional statement

Tags: python

I have this bit of code that I am stuck with and I am not sure why it won't execute the else statement. If x is "100" I would like to to convert decimal value to 6 bits otherwise for x = "115", "130", "145" I would like convert decimal value to 8 bits.

```
string_list = ["100", "115", "130", "145"]

if (x == "100" for x in string_list):
    dec_to_bin = "{0:06b}".format()
    
else:
    dec_to_bin = "{0:08b}".format()
```

However, it doesn't carry on the else statements and print everything in 6 bits.

I want the answer to be something like this

100 6bits

115 8bits

130 8bits

145 8bits

Comment: Because you've created a generator which is truthy

Comment: The `if` should be inside the `for`, `for x in string_list: if: .. else: ...`

Comment: As @Sayse mentioned, `x == "100" for x in string_list` creates a generator. You need to loop first (i.e. `for x in string_list:`) and then check the result of `if (x == "100"):`.

Comment: @dit Your code doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

As @Sayse mentioned in comment, the usage of `for` loop is incorrect:

Try this:

```py
string_list = ["100", "115", "130", "145"]
res = []

for x in string_list:
    if x == "100":
        dec_to_bin = "{0:06b}".format(int(x))
    else:
        dec_to_bin = "{0:08b}".format(int(x))
    res.append(dec_to_bin)

print(res) #Will print ['1100100', '01110011', '10000010', '10010001']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the condition which returns a True/False response after the if in parantheses, so it doesn't iterate through every element.
You are basicly writing "if there is an x=="100" in string_list, do this".
For it to work for every element, just write it:

```
for x in string_list:
  if x == "100":
    dec_to_bin = ...
  else:
    dec_to_bin = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write your `if` statement by passing `(x == "100" for x in string_list)` in the condition you are creating a generator which is not `None`, hence trigerring the `if` statement.

It is not iterating over each element as you are hoping it would. For it to iterate over each element, write the if statement inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is never executed. Your fist statement is an `if` statement.

You want to assess is a specific item is equal to `'100'`, and do something if it is. However the line `if (x == "100" for x in string_list)` actually generates an item called `generator`which is not `None`. Hence the fact that the if statement is always executed : your generator is always truthy.

You should try and parse the list, and only then for each item use an `if/else` statement :

```py
for item in string_list :
  if item == '100':
    # action
  else :
    # other action
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that output from those input data then:

```
string_list = ["100", "115", "130", "145"]

for e in string_list:
    n = 6 if e == '100' else 8
    print(f'{e} {n}bits')
```

**Output:**

```
100 6bits
115 8bits
130 8bits
145 8bits
```

**Alternatively:**

```
string_list = ["100", "115", "130", "145"]

for e in string_list:
    n = 6 if e == '100' else 8
    print(f'{e} {int(e):0{n}b}')
```

**Output:**

```
100 1100100
115 01110011
130 10000010
145 10010001
```

**Note:**

Not sure of the relationship between "100" and 6 because the binary representation of 100 (base 10) requires 7 bits